# MVC3 app using asp.net membership /claims aware application + STS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, wif

I have this in mind. 
I just want to check if there is something like what I have in mind already done, or I should I want to work on:

**MVC3 application using asp.net membership, that has single sign on (so it is a claims aware 
app that will log on a STS).**

I have seen http://identityserver.codeplex.com/ but not analized it in detail: 
Is it a good solution to implement?

My question is: 
Is there anything like that done?
Is it a common way of doing SSO? (using also membership?)

Thanks!..

Answer (score 0):

IdentityServer is an STS not an application.

If you have a claims-aware application, it "emulates" the membership provider. You can configure ADFS to provide the roles and then use the standard .NET constructs

IsInRole() or

location>
...
allow role = ...>

in the web.config.